# My equation seems to no be working, but looks right

Tags: python, python-3.x, gambling

i am a amateur python coder, i am trying to make a double or nothing gambling game, basically you bet a certain amount of money, you have the chance of either getting double what you put in or losing what you put in.

It seems that when i run this script i put a bet in and nothing happens the money label does not change, im not sure how to debug.

```
from appJar import gui
import random

# GUI Tab Name
win = gui('Double or Nothing')
# Starting Money

# Declares the odds
array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

# declaring the random array choice.

random = int(random.choice(array))

# starting money amount.

money = 500

# This is the define for the 'Insert Bet' button.
def press(name):

    bet = int(win.getEntry('Bet'))

    if name == 'InsertBet':
        win.setLabel('outcome', int(random))
        outcomes = int(win.getLabel('outcome'))
# The formula used to deduct and add Winnings
# If random is a number larger than seven, i would like to deduct
        if random >= int(7) :
            money == (int(money) - bet) + (bet * 2)
            win.setLabel('showMon', '$' + str(int(money)))

        elif random <= int(6) :
            money == int(money) - bet
            win.setLabel('showMon', '$' + str(int(money)))


# To Display How much money you have.

win.addLabel('showMon', '$' + str(int(money)))
win.addLabel("Insert amount money")
win.addEmptyLabel('outcome')
win.addEntry('Bet')
win.addButton('Insert Bet', press)

# start the GUI
win.go()
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and paste it on this site; us answerers are far too lazy to click on a link to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Your problem</s> One of your problems is in these two lines:

```
money == (int(money) - bet) + (bet * 2)
...
money == int(money) - bet
```

This is checking whether `money` is equal to `(int(money) - bet) + (bet * 2))` and `int(money) - bet` respectively. Use `=` to set `money` to a value.

The other problem, as pointed out by [blhsing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52888005/5223757), is that you're checking whether the `"Insert Bet"` button is called `"InsertBet"`, which is isn't; therefore you're not running the button-press code at all!

```
if name == 'InsertBet':
```

should be

```
if name == 'Insert Bet':
```

---

The first error is almost *always* the other way around! Congratulations on being creative with your bugs. :-p

Comment: Thankyou for trying to assist me, but it still seems to be in the same state i was thinking i would need to use a loop some where, but im not sure where i would, but changing the == too = didnt seem to be the fix. :/

Comment: @LukeKendon blhsing's answer gives the other problem, which I didn't notice.

Comment: I have fixed up the the previous issues,

Comment: but now when i attempt to bet 10 and then i press button

Comment: i get a error              money = int(money) - bet
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'money' referenced before assignment

Comment: @LukeKendon Oh, yeah; you need `nonlocal money` near the top of that function so Python knows not to try to create a new `money` variable local to that function. `nonlocal` makes it use the version of `money` that isn't local to it.

Comment: I have never used the 'unlocal declarations' ,  but how far at the top should i insert it, as it says SyntaxError: nonlocal declaration not allowed at module level

Comment: @LukeKendon Inside the `press` function, before you use `money`.

Comment: i put it inside the press on line 23 just after the `bet = int(win.getEntry('Bet'))`

Comment: but i got a error stating `SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'money' found`

Comment: @LukeKendon You've still got the `money = 50` line outside the function? You need that.

Comment: I have it to giving a starting amount of money, do you think i should remove it?

Comment: @LukeKendon No. If you keep it, there's no reason that you should have that `SyntaxError`... I know what I said earlier, but could you pasteee the code you've got now and link to it in a comment?

Comment: Have a look at line 23

Comment: @LukeKendon I messed up, sorry. It should be `global`, not `nonlocal`. See [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/#proposed-solution).

Answer (score 1):

The name in your condition needs to match the name you initialize the button with:

Change:

```
if name == 'InsertBet':
```

to:

```
if name == 'Insert Bet':
```